# Webpack For Large Module Project - Reduce Build Time

Tags: reactjs, webpack, babel-loader

My project currently has around 10000 custom classes and the build time takes minutes.

This is a react project which uses webpack 5,  babel-loader 8.0.

I have manage to lessen load times by adding cache=true, and persistent cache for webpack 5.

It's a really large project and there is only one entry point for the application currently.

I'm currently around 3 minutes mark but would like to ask what is the proper approach for lowering this ? Should I refactor my application to libraries in order to avoid building ?

Bulk of the time is spent in building modules. The application really has a lot of modules. What are my options moving forward ?

69% building 3794/3816 modules.

As  per the progres plugin

```
<w> [webpack.Progress] 131515ms building
<i> [webpack.Progress] 80ms finish module graph
<i> [webpack.Progress] 97ms dependencies optimization
<i> [webpack.Progress] 92ms chunk graph
<i> [webpack.Progress] 31ms advanced chunk optimization
<w> [webpack.Progress] 22680ms chunk modules optimization
<i> [webpack.Progress] 65ms module order optimization
<i> [webpack.Progress] 20ms module id optimization
<i> [webpack.Progress] 12ms after chunk id optimization
<i> [webpack.Progress] 373ms hashing
<w> [webpack.Progress] 6864ms chunk assets processing
<i> [webpack.Progress] 14ms additional chunk assets processing
```

THanks,

Comment: In my project build time is ~3 min, but during development I use webpack-dev-server and re-build time after changes is < 5 seconds, so why one should care about usual build time?

Comment: Yes, actually we are using webpack-dev-middleware and not middleware already. Changes reflect fast but to start the server it still takes long. Is there a way for them to cache previous results by loading from disk? Or is there a way that I can still lower the 3 minutes despite the large amount of classes.